# Enumerating process handles, weird issue

Tags: c++, process, handle

I scan for opened handles to my process and print them in the console.

1. I start my process
2. I attach cheat engine
3. I run the enumeration of opened handles
4. I see which process has a handle to my process

The weird issue at this point is as follows, check the code:

```
array<Accessor^>^ AntiCheat::ScanHandles()
{
    List<Accessor^>^ accessorList = gcnew List<Accessor^>();

    if (!EnableDebugPrivilege(true))
        printf("EnableDebugPrivilege failed: %d\n", GetLastError());

    tNtQuerySystemInformation oNtQuerySystemInformation = (tNtQuerySystemInformation)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtQuerySystemInformation");

    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION handleInfo = new SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;
    SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS infoClass = (SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS)16; // SystemHandleInformation
    DWORD size = sizeof(SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION);
    DWORD needed = 0;
    NTSTATUS status = oNtQuerySystemInformation(infoClass, handleInfo, size, &needed);
    while (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        if (needed == 0)
            return nullptr;
        // The previously supplied buffer wasn't enough.
        delete handleInfo;
        size = needed + 1024;
        handleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)new BYTE[size];
        status = oNtQuerySystemInformation(infoClass, handleInfo, size, &needed);
    }

    HANDLE currentProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    DWORD currentProcessId = GetProcessId(currentProcess);
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < handleInfo->dwCount; i++)
    {
        //printf(".");
        SYSTEM_HANDLE handle = handleInfo->Handles[i];

        HANDLE procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, handle.dwProcessId);
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
            continue;

        HANDLE dupl = 0;
        if (!DuplicateHandle(procHandle, (HANDLE)handle.wValue, currentProcess, &dupl, 0, false, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
            continue;

        DWORD procId = GetProcessId(dupl);
        if (procId == currentProcessId)
        {
            printf("accessing us\n");
            char processName[MAX_PATH];
            GetModuleFileNameEx((HMODULE)procHandle, NULL, processName, MAX_PATH);
            accessorList->Add(gcnew Accessor(gcnew String(processName), handle.GrantedAccess));
        }

        CloseHandle(dupl);
    }

    return accessorList->ToArray();
}
```

If I uncomment the line with printf(".");, I see 3 opened handles to my process (cheatengine). If it's commented (runs way faster), there is no opened handle. However I don't know why this affects my code. Im surprised, does anyone know why this happens? Or how to find out how to find the handles without my printf("."); line?

Another issue is: each time I call the function, the number of allocated bytes duplicates. And I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe the first time calling a C IO function causes it to open handles to standard in, out, and error?

Comment: You are not ignoring array items where `handle.dwProcessId` equals `currentProcessId`, so you end up opening a new handle to your own process.  You are only interested in other processes where `handle.dwProcessId` is not equal to `currentProcessId`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau assuming the Handle is a process handle, GetProcessId gets the id of the handle, and if it equals to my process, I see its a handle to my process, which is what I'm looking for. Anyway the other problem is: The number of allocated bytes duplicate each call (NtQuerySystemInformation returns ERROR_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH).

Answer (score 1):

I see logic problems with your code.

You are not ignoring array items where `handle.dwProcessId` equals `currentProcessId`, so you end up opening handles to your own process. Since you are only interested in looking for other processes, you should be ignoring items where `handle.dwProcessId` is equal to `currentProcessId`.

You are not checking if `OpenProcess()` fails for any reason other than `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.  Do not call `GetLastError()` unless `OpenProcess()` actually returns NULL first.

You are not closing an opened handle if `DuplicateHandle()` fails. And why are you duplicating each source handle just to call `GetProcessId()` on it? You already have their process IDs from the array, so the whole `DuplicateHandle()`+`GetProcessId()` is completely unnecessary.

You are taking the wrong approach anyway.  Have a look at this discussion:

[Enumerating the processes referencing an object](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f0ce82bf-84af-4e19-b90a-83fcb61faad7/enumerating-the-processes-referencing-an-object?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)

> Use NtQuerySystemInformation with SystemInformationClass set to SystemHandleInformation. This fills in an array of SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION structures, which are defined as:
>
> ```
> typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION {
>     ULONG ProcessId;
>     UCHAR ObjectTypeNumber;
>     UCHAR Flags;
>     USHORT Handle;
>     PVOID Object;
>     ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
>  } SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;
> ```
>
> **Search for the entry corresponding to the handle you opened with ProcessID equal to GetCurrentProcessId(), then find all entries with the same Object pointer.**

Although the discussion shows the wrong declaration for `SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION`.  The following article shows the correct one:

[HOWTO: Enumerate handles](http://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-enumerate-handles_topic18892.html)

> ```
> #define SystemHandleInformation 16
>
> typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *_NtQuerySystemInformation)(
>     ULONG SystemInformationClass,
>     PVOID SystemInformation,
>     ULONG SystemInformationLength,
>     PULONG ReturnLength
>     );
>
> /* The following structure is actually called SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO, but SYSTEM_HANDLE is shorter. */
> typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE
> {
>     ULONG ProcessId;
>     BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
>     BYTE Flags;
>     USHORT Handle;
>     PVOID Object;
>     ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
>  } SYSTEM_HANDLE, *PSYSTEM_HANDLE;
>
> typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
> {
>   ULONG HandleCount; /* Or NumberOfHandles if you prefer. */
>   SYSTEM_HANDLE Handles[1];
> } SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;
> ```

With that said, try something more like this:

```
array<Accessor^>^ AntiCheat::ScanHandles()
{
    List<Accessor^>^ accessorList = gcnew List<Accessor^>();

    if (!EnableDebugPrivilege(true))
        printf("EnableDebugPrivilege failed: %d\n", GetLastError());

    tNtQuerySystemInformation oNtQuerySystemInformation = (tNtQuerySystemInformation) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtQuerySystemInformation");

    DWORD currentProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();
    HANDLE currentProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, currentProcessId);
    PVOID currentProcessAddr = nullptr;

    DWORD size = sizeof(SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION);
    DWORD needed = 0;
    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION handleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION) new BYTE[size];
    SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS infoClass = (SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS) 16; // SystemHandleInformation
    NTSTATUS status = oNtQuerySystemInformation(infoClass, handleInfo, size, &needed);
    while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
    {
        // The previously supplied buffer wasn't enough.
        delete[] handleInfo;
        size += 1024;
        handleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION) new BYTE[size];
        status = oNtQuerySystemInformation(infoClass, handleInfo, size, &needed);
    }
    if (status != 0)
    {
        delete[] handleInfo;
        return nullptr;
    }    


    for (DWORD i = 0; i < handleInfo->dwCount; i++)
    {
        SYSTEM_HANDLE &handle = handleInfo->Handles[i];

        if ((handle.dwProcessId == currentProcessId) &&
            (currentProcess == (HANDLE)handle.wValue))
        {
            currentProcessAddr = handle.pAddress;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < handleInfo->dwCount; i++)
    {
        SYSTEM_HANDLE &handle = handleInfo->Handles[i];

        if ((handle.dwProcessId != currentProcessId) &&
            (handle.pAddress == currentProcessAddr))
        {
            printf("accessing us\n");

            HANDLE procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, handle.dwProcessId);
            if (procHandle != 0)
            {
                char processName[MAX_PATH+1];
                DWORD len = GetModuleFileNameEx((HMODULE)procHandle, NULL, processName, MAX_PATH);
                CloseHandle(procHandle);
                processName[len] = '\0';
                accessorList->Add(gcnew Accessor(gcnew String(processName), handle.GrantedAccess));
            }
            else
                accessorList->Add(gcnew Accessor(gcnew String("unknown"), handle.GrantedAccess));
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(currentProcess);

    delete[] handleInfo;
    return accessorList->ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You might want to open the handle to local process before you call NTQuerySystemInformation :)